# Java naming conventions versus English language correctness

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions

I'm not sure is this right place to ask so correct me if I'm wrong.

The case is that:

- one category has one code
- we want to get list of codes for multiple categories

Which version is correct and why?

```
getCategoriesCodes()
```

or

```
getCategoryCodes()
```

I see this problem from two points of view, one is the English grammar, and the second one is the clean code and code meaningful naming.

Please give me your opinion which method name is better and add note is English you native language.

Comment: As both a native English speaker and a Java programmer: `getCategoryCodes()` is preferable. `getCategoriesCodes` implies to me that I am getting multiple codes for each category, or that the codes relate to the collection of categories, rather than a code for each category.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but `getCategoryCodes` sounds to me like one category has multiple codes. To refer to a list of category having one code, I would name the method `getCategoryCodeList` or `listCategoryCode`.

Comment: But our case is tat we are having many categories.

Comment: As an example from "real" English: a car has one driver; you would refer to the drivers of many cars as "car drivers", not "cars drivers".

Comment: Really god example, in this case how we can we say about many drivers of one car?

Comment: "a/the car's drivers".

Comment: It makes sense, but we can't use't in java ;-) so how would you call your java method?

Comment: get "drivers of car(s)"

Comment: `getCar().getDrivers()` or `getDrivers(car)`, depending upon where the method is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both a native English speaker and a Java programmer: `getCategoryCodes()` is preferable. `getCategoriesCodes()` implies to me that I am getting multiple codes for each category, or that the codes relate to the collection of categories, rather than a code for each category.

As an example from "real" English: a car has one driver; you would refer to the drivers of many cars as "car drivers", not "cars drivers".

Answer (score 0):

I would side with the clean code and meaningful naming. Nobody will judge your English in your code and also looking at the code in a month or a year will make it easier to understand if its worded correctly

Comment: thx ;) Andy already fix it. But what is preference way?

Comment: @KirkoR I don't think he was referring to the English in your question, but rather what you should use in your code.

Comment: I was thing that he correct my question.

Comment: The only thing that I would add is: be consistent. Don't have `getCategoryCodes()` in one place and `getCategoriesThing()` in another.

Comment: @Andy, true that is important. But in case this will be the first method like this.

Answer (score -1):

There is no harm in giving names grammatical correct provided it is readable and understandable and not become very long because long names are difficult to understand.

Comment: I think you mean "provided" or "as long as", rather than "until". Also, long sentences are hard to understand.